# Away3D 3.6 Strange MovieMaterial Behaviour

Tags: away3d

I'm developing a very simple cube with Away3d 3.6 which has a MovieMaterial for one side.
The MovieClip I set as Material contains a videoplayer which, outside of the cube, works perfectly.
Unfortunately as soon as I use it as material it doesn't seem to update while the video is on focus but you can see it playing when I tween the cube rotation property.

Here is an example: http://clients.weborama.nl/files/campaigns2/2124906084/70549/IT_repubblica.it_D_moda_201401_index.html

Can anybody explain to me why is this happening?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it!
I noticed I removed the ENTER_FRAME event listener which rendered the scene when there was no need to do it.